# For Commerce, which UI display builders are supported?

Tags: commerce

I am trying to manage the display of products with Display Suite but have come across the issue of the display of variations and their prices. There was the suggestion in this issue but it is not a suitable alternative to use DS_Chains.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2723689

Reading through the issue queue Display Suite is not fully supported by Drupal Commerce and it is not clear if Layout Builder is supported either.

For the non-developers who want to work with Drupal Commerce, which of the UI display management modules are supported by Drupal Commerce?

Comment: I would probably attempt Layout Builder first since that is coming in 8.7.0. After that, I don't know how much life Display Suite will have left in it if it replicates most of that functionality.

Comment: I had tried Layout Builder after making this post and it is not working. It comes up with WSOD page error if you try it with a Commerce product. It seams like there should be support for at least 1 UI display builder.